# Apache rewrite rule to iis

Tags: iis, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, rewrite

I am trying to move site on apache to iis 8.5

All is ok, but 1 rule failes my site to run properly

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ [or]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} apple-touch-icon\.png$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Can someone translate it to IIS rewrite ?

I have found some examples to do it

```
<rule name="Webasyst Controller" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="!\.(eot|ttf|woff|js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="apple-touch-icon\.png$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

and

```
<rule name="Webasyst Controller" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="[^eot|ttf|woff|js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png]$|apple\-touch\-icon\.png$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Both of them dont work

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second example in your question:

```
<rule name="Webasyst Controller" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(\.(?!eot|ttf|woff|js|css|jpe?g|gif|png)|apple\-touch\-icon\.png)$" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: It couldnt work because there is OR expression in original.Maybe that apache rewrite log will help? I have no idea how to make it work, my thoughts is to go freelance sites to pay for writing those iis rules...

http://pastebin.com/zzQNDAqm

Comment: @IgorKuznetsov I've updated the rules. Please test them and tell me if the still won't work.

Comment: Still not work. Also, there are some rules in another folders.IIS rewrite dont care about .htaccess folder when convert it, so i added the path . Looks like it right, yes? http://pastebin.com/fwVnQuNN

Comment: @IgorKuznetsov It seems you can directly import mod_rewrite rules to IIS. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules

Comment: yeah they are exported . but they dont work:)

Comment: @IgorKuznetsov I've updated the entire rules group above. Please check again. I'm currently not on a Windows system, so can not check live.

Comment: Not working. I have some other .htaccess files, as i say.They are are very simple, but they are not in root ! If .htaccess file is in directory like "/var/www/example.com/templates/.htaccess" and file path is "/var/www/example.com/templates/silver/images/logo.gif" apache rewrite rule will work with "silver/images/logo.gif" . How to use it ? Its needed like  match url="wa-data\protected\wa-installer\backup\wa-apps\shop\lib\config\data,...^(.*)$" and something like <action type="Rewrite" url="D:\server\....thumb.php" . I dont now why iis rewrite converter dont care about .htaccess folder,

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. There was a damn bug in iis config.Php handler was set to file only. Set it to file and folder - all works... :)